# In Android, how to switch the page

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving from One activity to next in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803484/moving-from-one-activity-to-next-in-android)

i have two classes, how do I switch from one page to another page?

Comment: I think, you mean, how to switch activities in Android. [Here is a link to an existing post about your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803484/moving-from-one-activity-to-next-in-android).

Answer (score 3):

Both classes have to extend Activity, and be defined in the AndroidManifest.xml

To start Class2 from Class1 do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Class1.this, Class2.class);
startActivity(i);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="Class1"
                  android:label="Class1">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="Class2" android:label="Class2"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

One page into other page in the sense..Is it another activity?
In case of another activity u need to call that activity using `intent` only..

`Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setClass(firstclass.this,SecondClass.class);
 startActivity(intent);`

Also go through this link..
[start a new activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of Intents.
Just use the following code in one of the page

```
Intent i=new Intent("completepagename");
startActivity(i);
```

where the page name A is like
  packagename.A

Answer (score -1):

you have to defined the activity in manifest file and both class have extend the class
`Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.intent.action.NEW_ACTIVITY);
startActivity(i);`

In Android Manifest.xml

`<activity android:name="Baseclass"
                  android:label="BaseClass">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="NewActivity" android:label="NewActivty">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_ACTIVITY" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>`