# Navigate to MainActivity from Startup Activity causes close animation

Tags: android, android-activity, in-app-billing

I am using the below code to check in startup activity of the app for the Premium version,  but when it moves to Main activity, the startup activity is closed and creates a close animation and opens up new activity. How to avoid animation of closing startup activity while moving to Main Activity?

```
    if (checkForPremium()) {
        sendToMainActivity();
    }
private void sendToMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartUp.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving from One activity to next in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803484/moving-from-one-activity-to-next-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`overridePendingTransition(0, 0)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) to disable activity transition animations.

Comment: Awesome man,you understood my problem and gave pin-point solution. You nailed it. Thank you.